# oAuth Login using react-github-login not returning token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, authentication, oauth

I am developing a web application on React. I have added 3 authentication through facebook, GitHub and Google.

I have added the facebook authentication using 'react-facebook-login' npm package. And similarly for Google using 'react-google-login' and for GitHub using 'react-github-login'.

The facebook and google login is working fine, returning me an object containing token id, my user name, email and many more details.

My problem and question is on GitHub login. It is only returning me an object containing a 'code' property and value as given below -

```
{    
    code: "bd37ebf571b78b0c235c"
}
```

Questions-
1. Why is Github login not returning me other necessary details like facebook and google are returning?
2. Just to confirm, are the packages that I am using for the 3 logins correct?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere in the Github documentation where they support OpenID Connect and they don't support the implicit Oauth2.0 grant either.

Their [documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/) states:

> Note: GitHub's OAuth implementation supports the standard
>   authorization code grant type. You should implement the web
>   application flow described below to obtain an authorization code and
>   then exchange it for a token. (The implicit grant type is not
>   supported.)

The github react package you are using says that the success callback will hold the authorisation code.

```
onSuccess
{function}

Callback for successful login. An object will be passed as an argument to the callback, e.g. { "code": "..." }.
```

You then have to call the Githib token endpoint to swap it for a token. This is documented on the [github developer's website](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/#2-users-are-redirected-back-to-your-site-by-github).

e.g.

[image]